# new property can not be instantiated in derived class constructor

Tags: typescript

I was trying this piece of code in TS playground and came across this weird thing

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name: string) {
        this.name = name;
     }
}

    class Snake extends Animal {
        constructor(name: string, isPoisonous: boolean) {
            super(name);
            this.isPoisonous= isPoisonous;
        }
    }
```

As soon as I introduced the `isPoisonous` property in `Snake` constructor TS yells at me saying `'Property 'isPoisonous' does not exist on type 'Snake''`. Interestingly the same thing in ES6 compiles fine.

Comment: You're missing the access level that would make `isPoisonous` a parameter property, or the separate definition of the property that would allow you to leave it out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe point! does that mean TS needs an access specifier while instantiating a prop in ctor without declaring it?

Comment: It needs some definition to allow the assignment, either a parameter property (in which case the direct assignment is redundant anyway; your Animal constructor has a pointless line) or the regular kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the access level (ie `public`) in order to set something as a class variable as opposed to just a parameter to the constructor. So, adding `public` before the value would solve your problem.

That said, as a matter of style, it is probably better to forward-declare these properties:

```ts
class Animal {
  public name : string;

  constructor(public name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
  public isPoisonous : boolean;

  constructor(name: string, isPoisonous: boolean) {
    super(name);
    this.isPoisonous = isPoisonous;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, in the Animal class it doesn't need a declaration for name (try removing that). Should not be different for Snake class as well.

Comment: @izengod because you are missing `public` in front of the property.  It is being interpreted as a parameter rather than a variable.

Comment: ahh gotcha! I still have some ambiguity though when comparing to ES6 characteristics. constructors of a class in ES6 are basically an alternative to older function constructor in javascript which works fine with prototype chain in similar situations as the question. What bothers me is how does the introduction of static typing in TS change the scenario. any article or explanation would be great.